# Visualize a Nim board like an expert

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Background

In the [game of Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), players alternate removing "stones" from "piles": on each turn, a player must remove between one and all stones from a *single* pile.  The object of Nim is to take the last stone or, in the misere variant, to force your opponent to do so -- however, it turns out the strategies are nearly identical.

Nim makes a fun bar game. You can use matchsticks or coins for the "stones," and the "piles" are typically arranged in a line.  Below is a classic setup with piles of 1, 3, 5, and 7:

[image: nim with matchsticks]

If you've never played Nim before, you might try your hand at it before attempting this challenge.  Here's a [version called "Pearls Before Swine"](https://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/pearl2).

### Strategy

Optimal strategy in Nim is tricky enough that most lay people lose consistently to an expert, but simple to describe with [binary arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory).

Doing mental binary XOR operations, however, is tough, so luckily there is an  equivalent way to visualize the correct strategy which is easier to implement in real time, even when drunk.

There are only three steps:

1. Mentally group the "stones" in each line into subgroups whose sizes are powers of 2, starting with the largest possible size: 8, 4, 2, and 1 are sufficient for most games.
2. Try to match each group with a twin in another line, so that every group has a pair.
3. If this isn't possible, remove unpaired "stones" from a single line (this will always be possible - see the Wikipedia link for why) so that step 2. becomes possible.

Or, said another way: "Remove some stone(s) from a single pile such that if you then group the piles into powers of 2 all groups may be paired with a group in some other pile."  With the caveat that you cannot break up larger powers of 2 into smaller ones -- eg, you cannot group a line with 8 stones into two groups of 4.

For example here's how you'd visualize the board above:

[image: balanced matchsticks]

This board is perfectly balanced, so you'd want your opponent to move first.

### The Challenge

Given a list of positive integers representing the size of Nim "piles", return a plain text visualization of the Nim board as seen by an expert.

What constitutes a valid visualization is best explained by example, but you must:

1. Assign a distinct character to each "power-of-2 subgroup" and its pair (unpaired subgroups do not qualify), and use that character to represent the "stones" in both subgroup and pair.
2. Represent any unpaired "stones" (ie, the ones an expert would remove when playing normal -- not misere -- Nim) using a hyphen: `-`.

There will be multiple ways to achieve a valid visualization, and all are valid.  Let's work through some test cases:

### Test Cases

#### Input: 1, 3, 5, 7

Possible Output 1:

```
A
BBA
CCCCD
CCCCBBD
```

You may optionally include spaces between the characters, as well as blank lines between the rows:

Possible Output 2:

```
A

B B A

C C C C D

C C C C B B D
```

#### Input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

The order and choice of characters can be whatever you like:

Possible Output 1:

```
G
E E
E E G
C C C C
C C C C F
B B B B D D
B B B B D D F
H H I - - - - -
A A A A A A A A I
A A A A A A A A H H
```

Unicode symbols are ok too:

Possible Output 2:

```
◎
◈  ◈
◈  ◈  ◎
△  △  △  △
△  △  △  △  ◉
◐  ◐  ◐  ◐  ◀  ◀
◐  ◐  ◐  ◐  ◀  ◀  ◉
▽  ▽  ◒  -  -  -  -  -
▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ◒ 
▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▥  ▽  ▽
```

#### Input: 7

From the rules it follows that any "single pile" must be completely removed.

Possible Output 1:

```
-------
```

Possible Output 2:

```
- - - - - - -
```

#### Input: 5, 5

Possible Output:

```
A A A A B
A A A A B
```

### Additional Rules

- This is code golf with standard rules.  Shortest code wins.
- Input is flexible, and may be taken in whatever list-ish form is convenient to you.
- Output is flexible too, as the above examples illustrate.  Most reasonable variations will be allowed.  Ask if you're unsure about something.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many stones each pile may contain, or to how many distinct characters will be necessary for the visualization? (In the extreme case, what if, for example, more than the number of printable ASCII characters were needed, or more than 255 distinct characters?)

Comment: @Doorknob You can assume that won't happen.  You could even assume the letters of the alphabet will be sufficient for any input.

Comment: @Jonah would this be valid output for the second test case? `["H","EE","EEH","CCCC","CCCCI","DDDDFF","DDDDFFI","AAAAAAAA","AAAAAAAA-","----------"]`

Comment: @ngn no bc you can only remove stones from 1 pile per turn

Comment: @Jonah I don't understand how you got `H H I - - - - -` in your eighth pile. 8 is a power of 2, so why not pair it up with a block from 9 (=8+1)?

Comment: @ngn you could, you have 3 piles with 8+, so you could make 3 possible pairs, with a different leftover row in each case.  valid solutions aren’t always unique

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be non-decreasing?

Comment: @Οurous no the input could come in any order

Comment: The sizes of groups in the lines must be decreasing, so any output containing a line like `AAAABBBB` or `ABB` would be invalid, correct? And there should only be one row with unpaired stones?

Comment: @Οurous I think the simple answer yes.  Technically `AAAABBBB` is actually invalid, and `ABB` is not -- but it makes the output less readable so I think just making decreasing within a line an explicit rule is best.

Comment: Do we need to minimise the number of stones marked for removal?

Comment: @Οurous no, the only requirement is to leave a balanced board

Comment: Should the strategy actually be something like, "remove some stone(s) from a single pile such that if you then group the piles into powers of two all groups may be paired with a group in some other pile"? As it's written it seems that for the `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` input a valid output would be `'0', '11', '110', '2222', '22223', '444455', '4444553', '66666666', '66666666-', '7777777788'` (or is this valid?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Your description is correct, and arguably clearer than mine.  That said, the `88` in your example would be prohibited by the "unpaired subgroups do not qualify" clause, forcing your `8`s to become dashes, creating dashes in two piles, violating the single pile rule.  So it is invalid according to the existing description.

Comment: The point was more about the "strategy" section, since it implies grouping each pile starting with the highest possible power of two - note that the `7`s are unpaired too. Also "unpaired subgroups do not qualify" does not really mean much to me as I read it :/

Comment: @JonathanAllan, Even there, your example does not conform to step 3: 'Remove unpaired "stones" so that all groups are paired off when it's your opponent's turn.'.  That said, if the description isn't clear to you it may be unclear to others, so I'll add your sentence to the description.

Comment: Step one seems to imply grouping the piles like I have above (effectively using the set bits in the binary representations), which may then lead to steps two and/or three not being possible - it's only when one then studies the example that it becomes clear that the piles are not formed like that (or that they need to be adjusted in some way to meet two and three). (...it's also a shame because I implemented a terse solution that relies on it)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, I am relying on the logic that all 3 steps must occur simultaneously.  So if you perform steps 1 and 2 but cannot perform step 3, you must adjust your solution to steps 1 and 2.  Which I can see being confusing.  I've added your description below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ruby, <s>169</s> <s>164</s> 148 bytes

```ruby
->a{s=eval a*?^
c=?@
m={}
a.map{|x|z=x-(x^s);[$><<?-*z,x-=z,s=0]if z>0
n=1
eval'x&1>0?[$><<(m[n]||c.next!)*n,m[n]=!m[n]&&c*1]:0;n*=2;x/=2;'*x
puts}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3vasJAEMS/31OsUKIeG71LTW2Nm/ge4QLXYKDQHGJUzvx59jSXVrDil4H9zczO8fx57Qug3o91U9H@or9B8yRjOSU7VlLTMb0o9aFpbVuT9Wc2q@ZR@hJvt4nPa7Q@1ViRUF8F1LFghiRzT6bWk7FIxuCsTI1q23xh9vY0mXODDtDEqeflXKqNiAynILLLQabcssP5VHVdX6SpRHhFCBHWSkXgOPulwWisRu9tsBHeET4QpLgP/msNyfD@Xj0pyAEGbjR82Psbu9H@Bw)

First, we initialize

- the nim-sum with `s=eval a*?^` (which is shorter than `a.reduce:^`)
- the variable `c`, which stores the first unused unique character
- a map `m` that maps power-of-two lengths to characters used to represent them

Then, looping over each pile, we run the following:

```ruby
z=x-(x^s);[$><<?-*z,x-=z,s=0]if z>0
```

Per [Wikipedia's strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory), if *nim-sum XOR pile* is less than *pile*, we should remove stones from that pile such that its length becomes *nim-sum XOR pile*. By storing the difference in the variable `z`, we can test to see whether this difference is positive, and if so 1.) print that many dashes, 2.) subtract it from the pile, and 3.) set the nim-sum variable to zero to prevent further stone removal.

```ruby
n=1
eval'[...];n*=2;x/=2;'*x
```

Now we "loop" over each bit and keep track of their values by repeatedly dividing `x` by `2` and multiplying the accumulator `n` by `2`. The loop is actually a string evaluated `x` times, which is far greater than the `log2(x)` times it's necessary, but no harm is done (aside from inefficiency). For each bit, we run the following if the bit is 1 (`x&1>0`):

```ruby
$><<(m[n]||c.next!)*n
```

Print a character `n` times. If we already printed an unpaired group of this many stones, use that character; otherwise, use the next unused character (advancing `c` in-place due to the `!`).

```ruby
m[n]=!m[n]&&c*1
```

If `m[n]` existed (i.e. we just completed a pair), then `m[n]` is reset. Otherwise, we just started a new pair, so set `m[n]` to the character we used (`*1` is a short way to make a copy of `c`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>150</s> <s>196</s> 206 bytes

```python
def f(p):
 c=48;s=[l*'.'for l in p];m=2**len(bin(l))
 while m:
  if sum(m*'.'in l for l in s)>1:
   for i,l in enumerate(s):s[i]=l.replace('.'*m,chr(c)*m,`s`.count(chr(c)*m)<2)
   c+=1
  else:m/=2
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/RboQgEHznK/btwBJbqbZXr/RHjMld6XqSABrQNP16i2hN@sTszOwsM/5M/eDEsnxhBx0dWU1AyfJ8CbIx2Sk/dYMHA9rB2F6sFFlm0NFP7ahhjMB3rw2CjUugOwizpXZdinYDx2ZgH8XqSIzmiUM3W/S3CWlgdWh0K03ucTQ3hTQGZJar3lPFIriGa66G2U30j2Lvgq156kEW8UUTsLaPUhDwOM0@Xkx17lud4x@p3ui1m8AQSICQO20KDs8cKg6vLdtnkagysS9R4HDm8MaheNosuzOq1YbKf3IRR7HGVkfiHhfn5Rc)

Comment: I don't think this works for `4, 9, 10`.

Comment: @Neil Nice catch, should be fixed now

Comment: Sorry, I managed to fool it again, this time with `14, 21, 35`.

Comment: It also fails for [1, 3, 4, 5], where it should remove the entire second pile.

Comment: @Doorknob, Is that required? The rules say `There will be multiple ways to achieve a valid visualization, and all are valid`

Comment: @Neil, Fixed for larger numbers now :)

Comment: @TFeld I think so, because currently (after removing one stone from the second row) it tries to pair one stone in the second row with the top row and one with the last stone in the bottom row. It should take the entire second row as a group, because it has a power-of-two number of stones.

Comment: @TFeld Doorknob is correct, in 1 3 4 5 you must remove the entire 2nd pile.  If you can make a pile of 2, you can't choose to split it up.  The strategy won't work if you do.  Note that there are still multiple correct visualizations, in that you can still select different sets of characters, spacing, etc.

Comment: Some golfs for [189 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/BboMwEETP8VfsLTZxaO1Cm0DdH0FIaVwTLNkGGVDUr6eOoVS9zc7MPu3232PbOT7PX6qBBvekQCBFdioHUZlkn@6bzoMB7aCvSyt4khjl8FU7bAhBcG@1UWALtNNimCy2j5VQNrDtDeSDlfIgdGmfBD9qtPuLEl0MlT6yWpjUq958SoUDILFUth5LEsRluKSym9yIfy3yzkmpD4Ih8GqcfODE62/L9Rs9ftN77UYwCKJA6IYrRuGFQk7hrSbrzKOVRfc1BBROFM4U2PNSWZshzReV/YtZGPkDm2/EFRfm@Qc).

Comment: And then a full program is [181 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7dasMwDIXv/RQiN7VdN5u9ZO2aeS8SAt2MRwS2E@KEbU@fKd0vCKTzSeeg8WPuh2RW/@5dURSrs9WpybYNclfuXocJAmCiGpeZi66J1kgZfOIvmHgQgr31GDzEMwO0eYk8bj5yBPg1Z/GkG7e32MQbaw7I/q0knnOLB93ZUE5@DM/OcwqQUbl@4k7QcMmX0g1LmvkPEo9GNLi3mo0TphnySp/L49pqBXcKagXHjm3CXHV1RfdEFZwUPCjQt7TfbojX1Ko/qmk2W079FfHt7z4B)

Comment: You may also set `c=m=2**len(bin(l))`, since the characters don't matter as long as they are distinct, but you'll get some really gnarly outputs! (EDIT: oh, actually you want to stay in range(256) of course. But I _guess_ there's no reason c=1 wouldn't be allowed, say.)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 215 bytes

```js
f=
(a,c=0,x=eval(a.join`^`),i=a.findIndex(e=>(e^x)<e),b=a.map(_=>``),g=e=>(d=e&-e)&&a.map((e,i)=>e&d&&(a[i]-=d,b[i]=(c++>>1).toString(36).repeat(d)+b[i]))&&g(e-d))=>g(eval(a.join`|`),b[i]='-'.repeat(a[i]-(a[i]^=x)))||b
```

```html
<textarea oninput=o.textContent=/\d/.test(this.value)?f(this.value.match(/\d+/g)).join`\n`:``></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Only visualises up to 36 different characters. I'm relieved this works for `1, 3, 4, 5`.

Comment: Really nice.  It's fun to play with it in real time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 454 bytes

*still golfing*

```
import StdEnv,Text,Data.List
$p=join"\n"[{#toChar c+'-'\\c<-e}\\e<-[take i(e++[0,0..])\\e<-r[[~c\\c<-reverse e,_<-[1..c]]\\e<-hd[q\\q<-foldr(\h t=[[a:b]\\a<-h,b<-t])[[]][[c\\c<-subsequences(takeWhile((>=)k)(iterate((*)2)1))|sum c<=k]\\k<-p]|sum[1\\a<-q&b<-p|sum a<>b]<2&&foldr(bitxor)0(flatten q)==0]]1&i<-p]]
r[]_=[]
r[h:t]n|all((<)0)h=[h:r t n]
#[m:_]=removeDup[e\\e<-h|e<0]
#(a,[x:b])=span(all((<>)m))t
=r([[if(e==m)n e\\e<-k]\\k<-[h:a]++[x]]++b)(n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBjpswEL3zFdZmlbUbQLCrVaUI59L0UGkPlbZSD4MVGWcobsCAMVGqZvvppQ5U2otHM@/5vXmjapRmatrjWCNppDaTbrrWOvLqjp/NOfyGFxfupZPxix5ccN/xn602d7m5g98r136qpCVq8xA95LnKInzLc8wicPKERFPcbCAJkzgWbJ5bgD9qJlo8ox2QYHjw9DSOlRAzpTpCn@d9FpVtfbQ0r4jjAHJbeFh6OCyyyAkGIATAojWMxYD9iEbhQG/O3ytdI6U7zk6MaodWOt9@YI8sZew6jA1RGT95wVMWdeI2gHRW79devZsZMtsVIntcr5c9Cu0urWUJLWvpHBrSM84TIdK1vmmIwII4cLjVauuEucq6pjRjCau4n1jiiBHBCprtQXCLTXvG/dgBLpmvmCUepTKEi0/K@NBJQxeJHWsYcwG3FECXFDlvmCHLx/8ZvIEU/tQX4d@CUbNJ2fTqpHXBinT@FgPhBNKQPIXkOSQfvRUpR6Ocbo1H7gP@3s706a/yOX8MU/TlZdr/MrLRamm@@vhla5spqqbnJPG1@Ac)

Defines the function `$ :: [Int] -> String`, taking the pile sizes and returning a string where `-` denote stones to be removed, and groups are represented by ASCII characters ascending from `-`. 
If enough groups are needed the characters will wrap back around eventually, and due to the `foldr` it requires more than a gigabyte of memory to run the second test-case.

Indented version of the giant comprehension:

```
$p=join"\n"[
    {#
        toChar c+'-'
        \\c<-j
    }
    \\j<-[
        take i(e++[0,0..])
        \\e<-r[
            [
                ~c
                \\c<-reverse e
                ,_<-[1..c]
            ]
            \\e<-hd[
                q
                \\q<-foldr(\h t=[
                    [a:b]
                    \\a<-h
                    ,b<-t
                ])[[]][
                    [
                        c
                        \\c<-subsequences(takeWhile((>=)k)(iterate((*)2)1))
                        |sum c<=k
                    ]
                    \\k<-p
                ]
                |sum[
                    1
                    \\a<-q
                    &b<-p
                    |sum a<>b
                ]<2&&foldr(bitxor)0(flatten q)==0
            ]
        ]1
        &i<-p
    ]
]
```

Comment: Just curious, Clean seems similar to haskell... what are its advantages over Haskell?

Comment: @Jonah It is quite similar, yes. Off the top of my head, it has lower-level type manipulation, inline IL / Assembly, and interop with C all achieved easier than with Haskell. However, for actual use, due to the obscurity and experimental/academic nature of Clean, I would recommend Haskell (which also has more support in terms of libraries, and reference information). I just happen to like Clean is all.